# How can I get the keyboard Caps Lock state in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

In my project, how to keyboard caps lock on state. i have refer this question [How can I get the Caps Lock state, and set it to on, if it isn't already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435221/how-can-i-get-the-caps-lock-state-and-set-it-to-on-if-it-isnt-already). but i am get solution in javafx. please give me solution.I am also ref for this site https://community.oracle.com/thread/2415027?tstart=0

Answer (score 3):

You will want this import:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
```

If you are wanting it on no matter what, just turn it on with:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, true);
```

If you want to check first if it is off, then turn it on:

```
if (!Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, true);
    }
```

Lastly, if you want to toggle between the two states:

```
if (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, false);
    } else {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, true);
    }
```

Comment: User asked for JavaFX, why would you introduce AWT then? Don't import a different window toolkit solely for CAPS LOCK detection.

Comment: @user1438038 Because back in 2014, there was no other option to get the states... This answer is no longer relevant, as I'm sure it's been introduced since then, so feel free to post a corrected answer (I wouldn't know; I don't use JavaFX anymore).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to query the capslock/numlock state directly in JavaFX 8.  Robert's solution uses the AWT Toolkit, which is not JavaFX, but should work for you.  You might want to [create a feature request in the JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/) for locking key state tracking.

Comment: Note an enhancement request has existed since 2012: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090882