# Get CapsLock-state in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, keylistener, capslock

I'm trying to build an input form with several checks. One of those is to check if CapsLock is active. It works if I try to build this function together with Java Swing, see code below. But in JavaFX, it DOES not work at all. I get the same state every time I check; it seems like my application just asks for the initial state, and then saves it, and present it further...

**JavaSwing** (Works just fine)

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK){
                System.out.println(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK));
            } else if(e.isShiftDown()){
                System.out.println("SHIFT");
            }
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK){
                System.out.println(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK));
            } else if(e.isShiftDown()){
                System.out.println("SHIFT");
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK){
                System.out.println(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK));
            } else if(e.isShiftDown()){
                System.out.println("SHIFT");
            }
        }
});
```

**JavaFX** (Always present the same state)

```
scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.CAPS){
            System.out.println("CAPS");
            System.out.println(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK));
        }
    }
});
```

Does anyone know why? What can i do?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529180/how-can-i-get-the-keyboard-caps-lock-state-in-javafx)

Comment: This question also contains why it works in Swing but not in JavaFX

Comment: Impossible, there is a bug about this https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090882

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** It seems like the issue is a windows related one. [This question has an answer that might work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020835/how-do-i-check-if-the-caps-lock-key-is-pressed)

This works for me with the following console output when pressing caps lock repeatedly:

> Capslock pressed
>
> Capslock state: true
>
> Capslock pressed
>
> Capslock state: false

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        //scene.setOnKeyPressed( event -> {
        scene.setOnKeyReleased( event -> {
            if ( event.getCode() == KeyCode.CAPS ) {
                System.out.println("Capslock pressed");
                System.out.println("Capslock state: " + Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK));
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**I'm not sure what the issue is?**

Comment: It's very interesting. Which Java version are you using? Do you use OpenJDK? Tested your code and it does not work as you declares :(

Comment: from your question i didn't realise you were using openjdk so maybe its a problem with openjdk - any particular reason why you are using it instead of oracle's jdk?

Comment: No, I'm not using OpenJDK... I using JDK 1.8.0_71... I thought you might use OpenJDK then you got it to work ... just a thought =)

Comment: Did you try to run your compiled jar on another machine? Just to see if it's your code/libraries or the machine/keyboard messing up?

Comment: I have tried to build a snapshot, and run it on a laptop... Same result... I have also tried with options of JDK-versions... No progress at all.. Still the same ... Very strange... The question is why do you got a different result? ;)

Comment: That is indeed weird. Could you try it with _66 or _72 to make sure its not a library issue? If that does not change anything, it is not a library issue. Do all the systems you tested with run the same os? [proof that it works for me :P](http://i.imgur.com/7vpqFJe.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107026/discussion-between-user2734182-and-johnrw).

Comment: It seems like the issue is a windows related one. [This question has an answer that might work for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020835/how-do-i-check-if-the-caps-lock-key-is-pressed)