# Toggle Caps Lock On Tooltip on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jtextfield

I want to warn a user when caps lock is on the way it is done on Windows when login. I have a `JTextField` where this should be shown. I have searched forums and found out that the check if the key is on or off we use `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)`. However,  I am not sure how to attach this to the text field.

Note: I do not want to pop up a dialog with the message that the caps lock is on.

**Question**: How do I show caps lock warning/tool tip on a `JTextField`?

Here is my code:

```
public class CapsLockWarningJTextField {

private JFrame frame;

CapsLockWarningJTextField() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JTextField t = new JTextField(10);

    // if (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(
    // KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)) {
    // t.setToolTipText("Caps Lock ON");
    // }

    frame.add(t, "cell 0 0");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new CapsLockWarningJTextField();

          }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the Caps Lock state, and set it to on, if it isn't already?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435221/how-can-i-get-the-caps-lock-state-and-set-it-to-on-if-it-isnt-already)

Comment: @MouseEvent Well, I do not want it that way. These questions are different! I want it to be shown on the way it is done on Windows when login in - the way it is shown [here](http://guijournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Win7-password-Caps-Lock.png)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By following the advice in this question: [Value Change Listener to JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield) you can add a listener to your jTextField.

In that listener you can check if caps lock is on whenever the document changes and warn them if it is. You would most likely want to set a flag as well so you only display the warning once, they may want to enter some or all of the password in caps.

Comment: Well this is working, thanks. I would play around with the labels to display the the desired icons as shown [here](http://guijournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Win7-password-Caps-Lock.png).