# If button pressed is CapsLk

Tags: java, keyevent

How to check that key pressed is CapsLk.

```
    if(e2.getKeyChar() == ?)
{

text_area.setText("CapsLk is pressed")

}
```

Comment: [are you looking for something like InputEvent#isShiftDown?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isShiftDown()) or check [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435221/how-can-i-get-the-caps-lock-state-and-set-it-to-on-if-it-isnt-already)

Comment: The answer by px06 is the required answer here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(e2.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK){
    text_area.setText("CapsLk is pressed");
}
```